# Wordpress: Customizer not showing, no error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is the part of my **functions.php** that doesn't work (I get no PHP ERROR, and also nothing showing up):

```
function calmar_studio_customizer_register ($wp_customize) {
        $wp_customize -> add_section('calmar_studio_colors', array (
                'title'         => __('Colors', 'calmar_studio'),
                'description'   => 'Modify the theme colors',
        ));
        $wp_customize -> add_setting('background_color', array (
                'default'       => '#fff',
        ));
        $wp_customize -> add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'background_color', array(
                'label'         => __('Edit Background Color', 'calmar_studio'),
                'section'       => 'calmar_studio_colors',
                'settings'      => 'background_color',
        ) ));
}
add_action('cutomize_register', 'calmar_studio_customize_register');
```

Comment: you have a typo in your code, the callback is 'calmar_studio_customize_register' while the function you have is 'calmar_studio_customizer_register' you want them to be the same

Comment: @jnhghy-JanteaAlexandru Thanks for that. But that didn't solve anyting sadly. Howcome I get no PHP Error and nothing? That's so weird. With an Error I atleast have something to freak out about.
Is there possibly something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly solving the issue, I grabbed the Sample from https://gist.github.com/Abban/2968549 and copied it into my functions.php file. Works perfectly. Now I have to make tweaks, and get the items to Display on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This could be  the plugin conflict issue. Please deactivate plugins and try.

Thanks.